# C# mysql login doesnt verify credentials properly

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, winforms

Hello im trying to create login form that saves your `UserID` to `Userdetails` class. But for some reason log in doesnt work.I  think there is somewhere mistake in `if (login.Read())` in  `validate_login` but im not sure. If i put messagebox to `if (r.valid)` it doesnt work so thats why i think somewhere in `if (login.Read())` . Any form of help would be welcome. Thanks.

I have tryed rewriting mysql query, ( `cmd.CommandText =` ) 
If i remove `if (r != null)` i get this error System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

r was null.

```cs
private void db_connection()
        {
            try
            {
                conn = "..connection string..";                           

                connect = new MySqlConnection(conn);
                connect.Open();
            }
            catch (MySqlException e)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        private LoginUser validate_login(string user, string pass)
        {
            db_connection();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "Select * from table2 where username=@user and password=@pass";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass);
            cmd.Connection = connect;
            LoginUser usr = null;
            MySqlDataReader login = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (login.Read())
            {
                usr = new LoginUser();
                usr.UserID = login["UserID"].ToString();
                usr.valid = true;
            }
            return usr;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                string user = username.Text;
                string pass = password.Text;

                var r = validate_login(user, pass); 
                if (r != null)
                {
                    if (r.valid)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("validated");
                        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
                        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", r.UserID));
                        UserDetails.m_gnUserId = Convert.ToInt32(r.UserID);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

`validate_login`  should work as follows:`validate_login` should run query and search for username and password that is same as textbox `@user` and `@pass`.
`button1_Click` should start that `validate_login`
Note:I know i need to hash passwords in my db and i currently dont. Its my next step after this.

Comment: in `validate_login` method , replace `LoginUser usr = null;` with `LoginUser usr;`. You don't have to give null since you are using `usr = new LoginUser();`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably because you return null,  if there were no such record in database.

```
 LoginUser usr = null;
```

If that's not what you want, you should return new LoginUser with field valid  set to false.

```
var usr = new LoginUser(){ valid = false };
```

And don't forget to check for that in your button's event handler.

Comment: So if i understand correctly i replace <code> LoginUser usr = null;</code> with <code>var usr = new LoginUser(){ valid = false };</code> and rewrite <code>if (r.valid)</code> to <code>if (r.valid==true)</> ?

Comment: Just remove check for null in button event handler and you will be alright.

Comment: If i replace  LoginUser usr = null; line with your code and remove check for null nothing happens and if i leave LoginUser usr = null; and remove check for null i get error message mentioned above. I undertand correctly that i need to remove if (r != null){} line so it looks like this  var r = validate_login(user, pass);
                if (r.valid)
                { }

Comment: Yes, you got it right. But i'm stuck with understanding what are you trying to achieve? Probably there are no such login and password in your database, that's why it won't show the message you want.

Comment: Well it should work something along those lines: when you press button1 it  validates that user acc exist in db by using validate_login(user, pass) (note:i currently have 2 users admin and test) and stores that users id (stored in db too) in class. and then opens another form with actual program. (havent programed opening that form for now just did message box thet sais "validated" so i know everything went well and its doing instructions from if (r.valid){}). But problem is when i click on that button1 nothing happens. It doesnt do anything from if (r.valid) {}.

Comment: Well if it doesn't return object with "valid" field set to true, then you should definitely check your database query, can't help there as i'm not familiar with MySql. Btw, debugging is your friend there: [link](https://tutorials.visualstudio.com/vs-get-started/debugging)